# I uninstalled ' python ipython python-imaging python-serial python-wxgtk2.8', making my desktop unusable. What can I do?

Tags: python, uninstall

I Just got a Rubik's futuro cube, and wanted to download the RFCsuite so i could start to program my own projects. I went online and it gave me these instructions:

> ## Installation instructions -- Ubuntu
>
> Install python packages:
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get install python ipython python-imaging python-serial python-wxgtk2.8
> ```
>
> In case of x64 system install i386 compatibility packages:
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get install ia32-libs
> ```
>
> Add udev rules file (to avoid conflict with modemmanager):
>
> ```
> sudo sh -c 'echo SUBSYSTEM==\"tty\", ATTRS{idVendor}==\"0483\", ATTRS{idProduct}==\"a0a2\", ENV{ID_MM_CANDIDATE}=\"0\" >
> ```
>
> /etc/udev/rules.d/95-futurocube.rules'
>
> Add user to dialout group to grant access to /dev/ttyACM* devices:
>
> ```
> sudo usermod -aG dialout <username>
> ```
>
> In some cases restart of x-session is needed to change of group
>   (above) take an effect.
>
> To launch application use
>
> ```
> ./rubiks-futuro-cube
> ```
>
> Tested on Ubuntu 12.04 64 bit, LinuxMint 15: Olivia (x86-64) Expected
>   to work on Ubuntu 12.04 32 bit, Ubuntu 12.10 32/64 bit

I copied the first line into terminal (i.e `sudo apt-get install python ipython python-imaging python-serial python-wxgtk2.8`). I had just finished that when i realised that I should probably wait for my IT teacher to help me.

I used

```
sudo apt-get remove python ipython python-imaging python-serial python-wxgtk2.8
```

But then It suddenly started to delete everything! I killed the window and reinstalled what it had deleted (apart from software centre). I thought it was all right but when I restarted my laptop, the launcher, switcher and menu bar was gone!! I can access terminal using tty1. What can I do?

Comment: re-install desktop and see if it fixes it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`python` is a required package for Ubuntu. Many of Ubuntu components are built using python.

I assume you have standard Ubuntu release (Unity), to fix it reinstall all missing packages using:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

If you have different release, here all available meta packages:

```
~$ apt-cache search .*ubuntu-desktop
ubuntu-desktop - The Ubuntu desktop system
edubuntu-desktop - educational desktop for Ubuntu
kubuntu-desktop - Kubuntu Plasma Desktop/Netbook system
lubuntu-desktop - Lubuntu Desktop environment
qtubuntu-desktop - Qt plugins for Ubuntu Platform API (desktop)
ubuntu-desktop-mir - System compositor for Ubuntu Desktop
xubuntu-desktop - Xubuntu desktop system
```

Comment: @TheEpicstarlord, Please, If this answer solved it for you, consider accepting it by clicking on check sign next to it to the left side. See https://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers and [about] , if helpful but not complete solution, you may prefer just up vote.  Otherwise, down vote it and write new answer for the working solution.  :) Let me know so I can vote up.